# How to stop switching true/false if value doesn't need to be changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple true/false switching function:

```
import {useState} from 'react'
const [ isTrue, setIsTrue] = useState(true)

function handleSwitcher(){
    {isTrue ? setIsTrue(false) : setIsTrue(true)}
}

<button onClick={()=>{
    handleSwitcher()
    console.log(isTrue)
}}>
   Set to true
</button>

<button onClick={()=>{
    handleSwitcher()
    console.log(isTrue)
}}>
   Set to false
</button>
```

If we click on both of buttons it will always render opposite to true or false. What I need is, if isTrue's value is false and I click on 'Set to false' button it doesn't change isTrue's value to true. Same to 'Set to true' button, it shouldn't change isTrue's value to false, when value is true.

Comment: Why not use `setIsTrue(false)` for "Set to false" and `setIsTrue(true)` for "Set to true"?

Comment: Is "const [ isTrue, setIsTrue] = useState(true)" this definition placed inside the component function or right below the import statements ? If it's outside the functional component it does not work.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah, that is solution )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a handleSwitcher, just set the desired value when you click on the button, then it will be exactly the way you want

```
import {useState} from 'react'
const [ isTrue, setIsTrue] = useState(true)

<button onClick={()=>{
    setIsTrue(true)
    console.log(isTrue)
}}>
   Set to true
</button>

<button onClick={()=>{
    setIsTrue(false)
    console.log(isTrue)
}}>
   Set to false
</button>
```

Comment: thank you! I was just complicating things up, I see :)

Answer (score -2):

you should use **setIsTrue(!isTrue)**

Comment: Your suggestion to use `setIsTrue(!isTrue)` would make the button work as a toggle, which is not what the OP is looking for.